# AS3 event capturing not working

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I know the different between event capturing and bubbling and how `stopPropagation` work.

**So why capturing not worked in my simple test?** There is no `stopPropagation` in the code.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class CapturingNotWork extends Sprite {
    public function CapturingNotWork() {
        var rect:Sprite = new Sprite();

        rect.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        rect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        rect.graphics.endFill();

        // CAPTURING NOT WORKED
        rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown, true);


        // BUT THE BUBBLING WORKED
        // rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);

        stage.addChild(rect);
    }

    function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent): void {
        trace("It's worked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event starts with the topmost parent (stage) and works down the display object hierarchy until reaching the original target.

When the useCapture parameter is set to true, the listener processes the event only during the capture phase and not in the target or bubbling phase. Your event never reaches the target (rect) as you can see on this image:

[image: Diagram of three event phases that occur when clicking the box]

Comment: Thank Wilson, I may misunderstanding the capturing phase. Can we says the capturing phase does not include the target, but the bubbling phase does?

Comment: It's not exactly like that. The 3 phases are separate. But you either listen for the capture phase or the target and bubbling phases. You can listen for all phases if you add 2 event listeners: one for the capturing phase and the other for the target and bubbling phases.